# Every Vuser should pick different file name

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance

Using JMeter Selenium for web based application so every Vuser should pick different file.
Ex:-" User1 ---->Payroll1,User2------>Payroll2,User3------>Payroll3,User4------>Payroll4......"
So written the groovy scripting  like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybml3.png)
Calling the parameter in the script as this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd20I.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLKsC.png)

But still EverVuser is picking the same file.
Ex:" User1 ---->Payroll1,User2------>Payroll1,User3------>Payroll1,User4------>Payroll1....
next iteration it is picking like
User1 ---->Payroll2, User2------>Payroll2,User3------>Payroll2, User4------>Payroll2,"

Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `${iter}` with `${__threadNum}` in your WebDriver Sampler.

A couple of notes:

1. It's not recommended to use real browsers for load testing neither by [Selenium Developers](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/)

   > Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.

nor by [WebDriver Sampler developers](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)

```
>Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.
```

2. When you choose `java` as the scripting language it's not a real Java, it's [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) interpreter, consider migrating to [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).