# Every Vusers should pick new file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance, loadrunner

Vusers- 10, Files -250 ,Duration - 3600

Target is to upload 250 Files and file names is Payroll0, Payroll1 ,Payroll2, Payroll3,....Payroll247, Payroll248,Payroll249, Payroll250.

Using JMeter Selenium for web based application so every Vuser should pick different file. Ex:-" User1 ---->Payroll1,User2------>Payroll2,User3------>Payroll3,User4------>Payroll4......" So written the groovy scripting like this [image]
[image][image][image][image]

But User1 ---->Payroll1,User2------>Payroll2,User3------>Payroll3,User4------>Payroll4....User9----->Payroll9, User10---->Payroll10 and every user is picking like this and while every user after completion of iteration it is picking the same file.

Followed this URL but still no luck for me [Every Vuser should pick different file name](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/52023/every-vuser-should-pick-different-file-name/52024#52024).

Target is to select Unique Each Iteration I mean every vusers should pick new file for every iteartion.

Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

In order to comprehensively help we need to see your:

1. CSV files in **text** form, not in the form of screenshots
2. Your [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) configuration
3. [Debug PostProcessor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) output for first 2 iterations

In general it looks like your script can be simplified, for example instead of `name1.csv` you could use a [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) or even replace everything but the WebDriver Sampler with a single [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md)